# Django how to update object with multiple fields which is already saved in Database

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a logic in Django which checks if User had already provided certain information. If not then it creates new object and save in the databse. And information was already there then it updates the same object with the new information. I'm making some mistake because it is able to create a new object but **not updating** it.

```
try: # Check if user already have data available
    data_created_or_not = UserUsageInfo.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id).data_available_or_not
except Exception: # If not available than, make it false
    data_created_or_not = False
if not data_created_or_not: # If its False then create new object
    UserUsageInfo.objects.create(user=request.user,
                                 space_used=used_space,
                                 space_allocated=allocated_space,
                                 folders_list=folders,
                                 files_list=files,
                                 files_hash_list=files_hash,
                                 data_available_or_not=True
                                 )
else: # If already there then update it
    UserUsageInfo.objects.update(user=request.user,
                                 space_used=used_space,
                                 space_allocated=allocated_space,
                                 folders_list=folders,
                                 files_list=files,
                                 files_hash_list=files_hash,
                                 data_available_or_not=True
                                 )
```

Comment: But here you also create an object in case `data_available_or_not` is `True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`QuerySet.update_or_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) for this:

```
UserUsageInfo.objects.update_or_create(user_id=request.user.id,
                                       data_available_or_not=True,
                                       defaults={
                                           'user': request.user,
                                           'space_used': used_space,
                                           'space_allocated': allocated_space,
                                           'folders_list': folders,
                                           'files_list': files,
                                           'files_hash_list': files_hash,
                                        })
```

So here we use `user_id=request.user.id` as filter as well as `data_available_or_not=True`. In case that exists, we update with `defaults`, otherwise we create a new object with `user_id=request.user.id`, `data_available_or_not=True`, and all the defaults.

Given the database engine you use supports this operation, this *can* result in a single query. If not, Django can emulate it (of course then it will cost multiple queries).

Answer (score 2):

Use Django's [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) for this.

```
obj, created = UserUsageInfo.objects.update_or_create(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try: # Check if user already have data available
    data_created_or_not = UserUsageInfo.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id).data_available_or_not
except UserUsageInfo.DoesNotExist: # If not available than, make it false
    data_created_or_not = False
if not data_created_or_not: # If its False then create new object
    UserUsageInfo.objects.create(user=request.user,
                                 space_used=used_space,
                                 space_allocated=allocated_space,
                                 folders_list=folders,
                                 files_list=files,
                                 files_hash_list=files_hash,
                                 data_available_or_not=True
                                 )
else: # If already there then update it
    UserUsageInfo.objects.get(user=request.user).update(
                                 space_used=used_space,
                                 space_allocated=allocated_space,
                                 folders_list=folders,
                                 files_list=files,
                                 files_hash_list=files_hash,
                                 data_available_or_not=True
                                 )
```

The problem is in else part, where you need to use 1st get then update.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal in two ways:
Simplest way is that you may use [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) method django provides `update()` method for queryset that means instead of using get() you need to use filter and then update the data as below:

```
user_info = UserUsageInfo.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
if user_info:
    user_info.update(**update_values)  # considering update_values as your dictionary containing all the information you want to add or update
else:
    UserUsageInfo.objects.create(**update_values)
```